# No overload for method matches delegate

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, event-handling, delegates

In my WPF project, I get the following error when trying to compile: No overload for 'FileDropStackPanel_Drop' matches delegate 'DragEventHandler'.

But I dont know where to change the DragHandlers delegate signature. If this is the right way.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Backup backup = new Backup();
        BackupFileManager manager = new BackupFileManager(backup);
    }

    private void FileDropStackPanel_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e, BackupFileManager manager, Backup backup)
    {
        SetValuesOfBackup(e, manager, backup);
        IsFileZip(manager, backup);
    }

    
    private void IsFileZip(BackupFileManager manager, Backup backup)
    {
        if (backup.FileExtentsion == ".zip")
        {
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(backup.FilePath, @"xyz");
        }
    }

    
    private void SetValuesOfBackup(DragEventArgs e, BackupFileManager manager, Backup backup)
    {
        //the filepath must be set first
        manager.SetFilePathOfBackup(e);
        manager.SetDictionaryOfBackup();
        manager.SetExtensionOfBackup();
        manager.SetNameOfBackup();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DragEventHandler has only 2 Parameters:

`private void FileDropStackPanel_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)`

You must define your variables `Backup backup` and `BackupFileManager manager` in the class as variables.

```
private Backup backup = new Backup();
private BackupFileManager manager = new BackupFileManager(backup);

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void FileDropStackPanel_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    SetValuesOfBackup(e, manager, backup);
    IsFileZip(manager, backup);
}

private void IsFileZip(BackupFileManager manager, Backup backup)
{
    if (backup.FileExtentsion == ".zip")
    {
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(backup.FilePath, @"xyz");
    }
}


private void SetValuesOfBackup(DragEventArgs e, BackupFileManager manager, Backup backup)
{
    //the filepath must be set first
    manager.SetFilePathOfBackup(e);
    manager.SetDictionaryOfBackup();
    manager.SetExtensionOfBackup();
    manager.SetNameOfBackup();
}
```

Comment: In which class? Backup and BackupFileManage are both seperate classes.

Comment: in class `MainWindow`